# How to groupby based on two columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

A similar question might have been asked before, but I couldn't find the exact one fitting to my problem.
I want to group by a dataframe based on two columns. 
For exmaple to make this

```
id product quantity
1  A       2
1  A       3
1  B       2
2  A       1
2  B       1
3  B       2
3  B       1
```

Into this:

```
id product quantity
1  A       5
1  B       2
2  A       1
2  B       1
3  B       3
```

Meaning that summation on "quantity" column for same "id" and same "product".

Answer (score 25):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with parameter `as_index=False` for return `DataFrame` and aggregating `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','product'], as_index=False)['quantity'].sum()
print (df)
   id product  quantity
0   1       A         5
1   1       B         2
2   2       A         1
3   2       B         1
4   3       B         3
```

Or add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['id','product'])['quantity'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   id product  quantity
0   1       A         5
1   1       B         2
2   2       A         1
3   2       B         1
4   3       B         3
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='sum'`

```
df.pivot_table('quantity', ['id', 'product'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()

   id product  quantity
0   1       A         5
1   1       B         2
2   2       A         1
3   2       B         1
4   3       B         3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby` and `aggregate` function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3],
    'product': ['A','A','B','A','B','B','B'],
    'quantity': [2,3,2,1,1,2,1]
})

print df

   id  product  quantity
0   1     A      2
1   1     A      3
2   1     B      2
3   2     A      1
4   2     B      1
5   3     B      2
6   3     B      1


df = df.groupby(['id','product']).agg({'quantity':'sum'}).reset_index()
print df

    id  product  quantity
0   1     A       5
1   1     B       2
2   2     A       1
3   2     B       1
4   3     B       3
```